# Prepared statements in DataTables

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I want to use prepared statements inside [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) for the code stated below. It has two queries (`query` and `query1`).

Query has two "where conditions" which variables are `$classid` and `$searchfield`.
Query1 is a "Limit" statement and also has two variables `$start` and `$end`.

The results of both queries should be stored in the `$data` array. At the moment I don't get any results. How do I bind the paramteres correctly in this case and store the results in the array so DataTables gets a working json?

**My try:**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$columns = array('itemOverview.id', 'itemOverview.Display_lang');

// Variables to bind

$classid = 4;
$searchfield = $_POST["is_searchfield"];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['length'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM itemOverview INNER JOIN item ON item.id = itemOverview.id";

$query.= " WHERE item.ClassID = ? AND ";

if(!empty($searchfield)) {
    $query .= "itemOverview.Display_lang = ? AND ";
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1) {
    $query1 = 'LIMIT ?, ?';
}

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query. $query1)) {
        echo "SQL Failed";
    } else {

        // bind paramaters to the placeholder
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $classid, $searchfield, $start, $end);

        // run parameters inside database
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        $data = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $row["id"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["Display_lang"];
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
}

$output = array(
   "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
   "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Firstly, you're concatenating a number of elements to make the final query. There's nothing wrong with what you're doing in principle, but it's easy to miss a comma, quote, or whitespace along the way. Echo out the actual query you've created and check that. Secondly, if your `prepare()` fails, don't just echo 'SQL failed'. Get the actual error from `mysqli_error()` and echo that too. Lastly, it sounds obvious, but be sure that your query will actually find some data.

Comment: You can't use parameters for LIMIT. And you need to use different arguments to `bind_param()` depending on whether you have a search field.

Comment: What do you mean with "use different arguments"?